# Data from gyroscope not work on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, swift, gyroscope

This code with accelerometer works fine on the Apple Watch

```
if motionManager.isDeviceMotionAvailable {
            motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.2
            motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { (data, error) in
                if data!.userAcceleration.z < -0.5 {
                    self.myOutlet.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.red)
                    self.myLabel.setText("Green")
                } else if data!.userAcceleration.z > 0.5 {
                    self.myOutlet.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.green)
                    self.myLabel.setText("Red")
                }
```

But if i'm trying to use Gyroscope

```
if motionManager.isGyroAvailable {
            motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 0.2
            motionManager.startGyroUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { (data, error) in
                if data!.rotationRate.y > 0.1 {
                    self.counter.addOne()
                    self.myLabel.setText("\(self.counter.toString())")
                }
            }
        }
```

they do not react in any way :( Apple Watch do not support access to Gyroscope or i do something wrong?

Comment: Did you get any update on this?

Comment: Unfortunately no